# BTree Visualization Tool

Tags: b-tree

I want a Visualization of BTree operations to learn the operations thoroughly. I found this Website which helped me:
[https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BTree.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/BTree.html)

Now I want to recreate a given BTree with this Tool but I can't figure out the right order to insert the elements.
For example, in which order should I insert the elements if I wanted to recreate following BTree with this tool above?:
[image: Example BTree]

My attempts lead to BTrees like this:
[image: What the tool creates]

But I want the exact BTree-Structure as the first image shows.

Also, is the fact that I write order M=4 but the Website sees my Interpreation of M=4 as M=5 just a different convention?

I hope this question is not too niche.

I tried different orders of Insertion but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed different conventions for describing the size limit of B-tree nodes.

That [visualisation tool](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/BTree.html) uses the concept of *maximum degree*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) defines *degree* as *"For a given node, its number of children."*. For a B-tree this means a node has a number of keys that is at most one less than that degree.

The tree you want to build has a root node with 5 children, so you should choose option "Max. Degree = 5".

There are many ways to achieve the desired result. One is to insert the keys from low to high, but skipping a key when a leaf node has 3 keys. So enter 2 and 4, but skip 6, then continue with 10, ...etc.

When you reach the greatest value, enter the few remaining values you have skipped. Here is the total insert sequence:

```
2 4 10 15 27 33 35 38 55 62 70 79 81 87   6 74 93
```

The result (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a general rule how to insert? So not specific on one example?

Comment: There are different algorithms. The tool gives you the choice between two. The alternative can be activated by clicking the "Preemtive Split / Merge" checkbox. But there are more than those two. For instance, when the degree is *even*, and a node is full, then you can choose between two "center" keys the one that should move up.